# http.ClientRequest doesn't end stream

Tags: node.js

For some reason when the status code is not `200` and I return then call the callback the executed script just hangs there, not exiting. Why is that?

```
var http = require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');

var args = {
  q: 'dfdfdf'
};

var opts = {
  hostname: 'api.openweathermap.org',
  path: '/data/2.5/weather?' + qs.stringify(args)
};
function cb(err, result) {
  console.log(err, result);
}

http.get(opts, function(res) {
  var buffer = new Buffer(0);

  if (res.statusCode !== 200) return cb(new Error('Unable to fulfill request.'));

  res.on('readable', function() {
    return buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, this.read()]);
  });

  res.on('end', function() {
    return cb(null, JSON.parse(buffer.toString('utf8')));
  });
});
```

Command line:

```
$ node plugins/weather.js
[Error: Unable to fulfill request.] undefined
# I have to ctrl+c at this point
```

Comment: as far as I see, you don't define `cb` either

Comment: you make exactly one request, if it is non 200 you call `return` and log the error. no further code is executed - oh "why is it not exiting". my guess something needs to be closed?

Comment: @Plato, but it should exit after returning. The problem is it does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You still need to consume the stream until it emits `end` event:

```
http.get(opts, function(res) {
  var buffer = new Buffer(0);

  res.on('readable', function() {
    return buffer = Buffer.concat([buffer, this.read()]);
  });

  res.on('end', function() {
    if (res.statusCode !== 200) return cb(new Error('Unable to fulfill request.'))
    return cb(null, buffer.toString());
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You never call `res.end()`. You should also do some `res.write` calls before `res.end()`.

Comment: can you pass data to `res.end()` with the standard `http` library? you can with express e.g. `res.end(200, '<h1> awesome!</h1>')`